# Проблема обработки событий мыши

Tags: c#, события, winforms

Есть свой контрол, при срабатывании MouseDown начинается перетаскивание. Однако, следющие события, такие как `Click/DoubleClick` уже не происходят. Как это обойти?

Comment: А как вы при нажатой кнопки мыши сделаете ещё один клик/дабл клик?

Comment: Мне не надо делать это одновременно. Это два разных события.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел для себя выход: повесить обработчик на MouseDown, вытаскивая из MouseEventArgs количество кликов, [как сделано здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs.clickcount.aspx). Также есть вариант с [таймером](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms171543.aspx)
Не понял почему люди минусовали вопрос :) По крайней мере никто ответ на него не дал.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте для перетаскивания [Drag'n'Drop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984430(v=vs.71).aspx) и, конкретнее, метод [DoDragDrop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop.aspx)

Comment: Я и использую метод DoDragDrop на MouseDown. Проблема в том, что если у меня уже висит обработчик на MouseDown, обработчик Click/DoubleClick никогда не срабатывает.

Comment: А MouseUp срабатывает? Может быть с помощью него обойти...